# Install Shiled 2008 - how to add a MSU (MSI?) as a prerequisite and install by condition

Tags: installation, windows-installer, conditional-statements, installshield, prerequisites

i have Install Shield 2008 Express Edition and a Setup project which create's a exe and and msi installer. Now as our application uses HLP files as a help system and HLP files are not supported natively on Windows Vista and newer i need to add to the setup an prerequsite installation of the Help Viewer for Windows Vista, 7, 2008  which can be downloaded from here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=258aa5ec-e3d9-4228-8844-008e02b32a2c### and is in MSU (Microsoft Update format)

Also i need to make a conditionall install which means that i need to detect if the setup is running on Vista, 7 2008 and then detect if 32-bit or 64-bit and the install the correct MSU. Is this possible and if yes how to do it in installshield 2008 express?

I see in the Redistributables section only predefined prerequisites. How can i add own, custom?

Answer (score 0):

The Express SKU of InstallShield doesn't provide a means for creating custom prereq (.PRQ ) files.  The files are simple XML documents though and with a trial version of InstallShield Pro/Prem. you could author one and then drop it in the directory for Express to consume.

Checkout my blog article describing how to author a prereq.  The details would depend on the specific MSU you are authoring.

[Using InstallShield 12 to Install .NET Framework 3.0](http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2006/11/using-installshield-12-to-install-net.html)